# Index notation for a Lagrangian with second derivatives

Tags: field-theory, notation

I'm finding the field equations for a hypothetical Lagrangian with dependence on the second derivative of a scalar field, $L\left(\phi,\phi_{,\mu},\phi_{,\mu\nu}\right)$, and in the analogue to the Euler-Lagrange equations I got a term that looks like $\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_{,\mu\nu}}$.

I'm still getting used to index notation -- Is $\partial_\mu\partial_\nu$ equivalent to $\partial_{\mu\nu}$?

If it is, is $\partial_{\mu\nu}\partial^{\mu\nu}\phi$ equivalent to $\square\square\phi$? (where $\square$ is the d'Alembertian)

Comment: Yes both of your statements are correct